# How to check if time is in range using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following times:

```
   now =  "2014-01-24T15:58:07.169+04:00",
   start = "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z",
   end = "2000-01-01T16:00:00Z"
```

I need to check if now is between start and end. I use the following code:

```
Range.new(start, end).cover?(now)
```

Unfortunately, this code returns false for my data. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: the code compares the whole date, including year, you have 2000 year range, but `now` has 2014. fix range to 2014 year

Comment: Can I compare only time?

Comment: has my answer been helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would use `between?` method. Because it's faster than `cover?` and `include?` variants. Here's an example:

```
yesterday = Date.yesterday
today = Date.today
tomorrow = Date.tomorrow

today.between?(yesterday, tomorrow) #=> true
```

Here's a gist with performance tests [Include?, Cover? or Between?](https://gist.github.com/julian7/4055746)

**Update**

According to your recent comment, you want to compare 'only time' without date. If I get you correctly, there's a way to do it - [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime). But before that, to make comparison correctly, you need to convert all your datetimes to a single timezone (for example, using [utc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-utc)). Here's an example:

```
start_time_with_date = Time.parse('2000-01-01T16:00:00Z').utc
end_time_with_date = Time.parse('2014-01-24T15:58:07.169+04:00').utc


start_time = start_time_with_date.strftime('%I:%M:%S') #=> '04:00:00'
end_time = end_time_with_date.strftime('%I:%M:%S') #=> '11:58:07'

current_time = Time.now.utc.strftime('%I:%M:%S') #=> '01:45:27' (my current time)

current_time.between?(start_time, end_time) #=> false
```

And yes. Sadly, it's a string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I see the only variant, to define additional method to `Range`:

```
class Range
   def time_cover? now
      (b,e,n) = [ self.begin.utc.strftime( "%H%M%S%N" ),
                  self.end.utc.strftime( "%H%M%S%N" ),
                  now.utc.strftime( "%H%M%S%N" ) ]
      if b < e 
        b <= n && e >= n
      else
        e <= n && b >= n
      end
   end
end

now =  Time.parse "2014-01-24T15:58:07.169+04:00"
s = Time.parse "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z"
e = Time.parse "2000-01-01T16:00:00Z"

Range.new(s, e).time_cover?(now)
# => true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range#cover?` with time objects.

```
start = Time.parse('2000-01-01T10:00:00Z')
end_time = Time.parse('2000-01-01T16:00:00Z')
now = Time.parse('2014-01-24T15:58:07.169+04:00')

(start..end_time).cover?(now)
```

You're currently using strings, Ruby cannot know you're speaking about time.

Comment: This will throw error. `end` cannot be used as a variable name

Comment: it also retrurns `false`

Comment: It throws `TypeError: can't iterate from Time`.

Answer (score 0):

your date time(now) is  not in between start and end time